# Querydsl StringExpression containsIgnoreCase encoding

Tags: hibernate, querydsl, mysema

I searched a lot for solution but i cannot find it. my problem is when i try to search persons name with containsIgnoreCase with turkish char 'İ' querydsl converts 'İ' to 'i ̇ ' i don't know how to solve this.

here is query:

```
kisi.adiUnvani.containsIgnoreCase('METİN')
```